# Is there a guide on porting edk2 to a new ARM64 platform?

Tags: arm64, edk2

I am new to EDK2.

For porting ekd2 firmware to a new ARM64 platform, it would be good  to first get a minimum edk2 port which can run UEFI Shell at least, improvements can be added gradually based on that.

It seems that the first step is rather steep, e.g., how to determine a minimal set of "items" in `.dsc` and `.fdf` file for a platform? In my case, I would like to build the `.fd` for my platform and treat it as BL33 of TF-A, effectively I would like to build an edk2 firmware to replace u-boot.

It seems that such a guide is hard to find on the web. I found a [old version of edk2](https://bitbucket.org/incubaid/edk2/src/master/ArmPlatformPkg/Documentation/) which contains some instructions, but apparently they are obsolete (not exist in latest `master` branch, while can be found in UDK branches such as `UDK2014`), and I am not sure why those documents are removed from `master` branch.

Currently I can build `.fd` for FVP (`edk2-platforms/Platform/ARM/VExpressPkg/ArmVExpress-FVP-AArch64.dsc`), and it seems that the build output `FVP_AARCH64_EFI.fd` is supposed to be treated as BL33. Theoretically this could be a prototype for my new ARM64 platform, but to me it's too complex to start with: the firmware is about 2.5MiB in size (as compare to 500K of u-boot), so I guess it's far from a "minimum" version. but it's hard to figure out what features to be removed (and how).

I am wondering if there is a detailed guide on such topic...

Comment: Hello, I am very interested in your post because I am doing the same project like that. Can you give me your contact (email, LinkedIn, Facebook, etc.) ? I would like to discuss with you more. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I really need your help, please response me when you see this comment. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, @Vietnamese. I am glad that you find the thread of interest. Unfortunately, I did not continue on this subject (EDK2) since then ... it was more than 2 years ago, and I almost forget the details...

Comment: Did you finally succeed in creating EDK2 Firmware for your platform? Which platform did you work with?

Comment: Did you succeed with this method?

Answer (score 7):

After 1 month of trial and error, today I managed to bring my ARM64 platform into a UEFI Shell environment. I treat it as my 1st milestone on the EDK2 journey. Below I will try to summarize the steps I took so far,  as a tentative answer to my question above. Guidance/corrections/comments are welcomed.

0. Get familiar with UEFI/PI spec and EDK2 implementation by reading books/specs/articles. Well, UEFI/PI specs are thousands of pages long...how to start? My main reading list is:

   - "Beyond Bios--Developing with the Unified Extensible Firmware Interface", 3rd ed, by Vincent Zimmer, et al. As the authors explained, the book is a kind of high level summary of the thousands-paged specs. And I find that the book is well organized for a new comer to get familiar with various UEFI related concepts.  The main purpose of the 1st read (before playing with edk2 code base) is to get familiar with concepts and architectural ideas, not the details yet. Related sections need to be consulted later when reading EDK2 implementations.
   - EDK2 specs, including:

     - EDKII User Manual
     - EDKII Build Specification
     - EDKII DSC/FDF/DEC/INF File Specification
   - Various articles on the web...
1. Get a reference platform which can correctly boot a FD image built from latest EDK2 source, and play with the boot manager and Shell environment a bit. In my case, I chose RPi4B. For me, this is very important, as the reference platform serves as a handrail during the whole process, that whenever I encounter bugs or have doubts, I check the source/log of the reference platform. This solves most of the problems I encountered. Btw, always generating "build log" and "build report" for both reference platform and the target platform, as the two files contains very detailed information for comparison and check. Consult the EDK2 build spec on how to generate these two files during build.

   I use the following script to build for RPi4B platform:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   # https://github.com/tianocore/edk2-platforms#how-to-build-linux-environment

   export WORKSPACE=/home/bruin/work/tianocore
   export PACKAGES_PATH=$WORKSPACE/edk2:$WORKSPACE/edk2-platforms:$WORKSPACE/edk2-non-osi

   pushd $WORKSPACE

   rm -rf ./Build/RPi4

   source edk2/edksetup.sh

   echo "Building BaseTools..."
   make -C edk2/BaseTools all

   #sudo apt install acpica-tools    # iasl
   # pip install antlr4-python3-runtime   # -Y EXECUTION_ORDER

   echo "Building firmware for Pi4B..."
   GCC5_AARCH64_PREFIX=aarch64-none-linux-gnu- build \
       -n 4 \
       -a AARCH64 \
       -p Platform/RaspberryPi/RPi4/RPi4.dsc \
       -t GCC5 \
       -b NOOPT \
       -v -d 9 -j RPi4-build.log \
       -y RPi4-build-report.txt \
       -Y PCD \
       -Y LIBRARY \
       -Y DEPEX \
       -Y HASH \
       -Y BUILD_FLAGS \
       -Y FLASH \
       -Y FIXED_ADDRESS \
       -Y EXECUTION_ORDER \
       all
   ```

   How to use the build result `RPI_EFI.fd` on RPi4B, consult the following:

   - `edk2-platforms/Platform/RaspberryPi/RPi4/Readme.md`
   - `readme.md` inside https://github.com/pftf/RPi4/releases/download/v1.17/RPi4_UEFI_Firmware_v1.32.zip. btw, I need to replace the original `start4.elf` and `fixup4.dat` with the ones in the zip file, otherwise, the boot of RPi4 will fail, complaining something like below:

     ```
     RpiFirmwareGetClockRate: Get Clock Rate return: ClockRate=0 ClockId=C
     ASSERT [ArasanMMCHost] /home/bruin/work/tianocore/edk2-platforms/Platform/RaspberryPi/
     Drivers/ArasanMmcHostDxe/ArasanMmcHostDxe.c(263): BaseFrequency != 0
     ```
   - It's worth to analysis the `RPI_EFI.fd` content to some extend, by using some UEFI utilities. I mainly use the GUI version `UEFITool` of `sudo apt install uefitool uefitool-cli`. Other tools are also available. The anotomy of `RPI_EFI.fd` is of help when reading EDK2 build specs for checking understanding of the concepts.

     - One special aspect of `RPI_EFI.fd` is that the 1st 128K is `bl31.bin` binary from ATF. I guess this is due to the special booting connfiguration methods for RPi. For my platform, I don't need such kind of packaging, I only need to build the UEFI image `MY.fd`, which is treated as BL33 image and packaged into `fip.bin` togehter with BL2 and BL31 images by ATF build script.
     - Another aspect to notice is the "reset vector" in the begining of the `.fd` file. This related to the entry point of UEFI image (and entry point of each EDK2 modules), as well as interpreting the `BL` instruction for AArch64. Basically, it can be summarized as below:

     The first `[Components]` in `RPI_EFI.fd` is `ArmPlatformPkg/PrePi/PeiUniCore.inf`, which is of `MODULE_TYPE = SEC`.

     - What's this component: this is the first (and only) `SEC` (Security) module in RPi4. What the name `PrePi` and `Pei` implies?

       > ... the PI spec is not tied to edk2 PEIMs, and I don't see where EDKII PEI modules are currently the only "acknowledged" silicon init environment. The edk2 tree itself seems to contain platforms that don't use the edk2 PEI module set at all, but (IIRC) jump from SEC to DXE. I believe "ArmPlatformPkg/PrePi" and "ArmVirtPkg/PrePi" are related to this.
       >
       > --- https://listman.redhat.com/archives/edk2-devel-archive/2020-November/msg00021.html
     - Its entry point: all UEFI components have the same entry point (`_ModuleEntryPoint`).

       - By "component", it means either a UEFI driver and UEFI app, both are PE32 executables, usually with suffix `.efi`.
       - The `.efi`s are converted from ELF executables (`.dll`) by `GenFw` tool: modifying the file headers.
       - To verify that "all components' entry point is `_ModuleEntryPoint`":

         - Check the `.dll` generating command line in build report (`build -y <BUILD_REPORT_FILE>`), we have two flags `"aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc" -o xxx.dll -u _ModuleEntryPoint -Wl,-e,_ModuleEntryPoint ...`:

           - `-u`: `gcc --help -v|grep "undefined SYMBOL"` gives `-u SYMBOL --undefined SYMBOL: star with undefined reference to SYMBOL`.
           - `Wl,-e`: `ld --help|grep "entry"` gives `-e ADDRESS, --entry ADDRESS Set start address`.
         - Check all `.dll` files that `Entry point address == _ModuleEntryPoint`: `find . -type f -name "*.dll" -exec sh -c "readelf -a {} |grep -E 'Entry point address|_ModuleEntryPoint'" \;`
     - Its entry point is the entry point of whole UEFI FD image (i.e., from `bl33_base_addr` jump to this `_ModuleEntryPoint`):

       > Topology of the UEFI Firmware File
       >
       > A UEFI Firmware File (actually a UEFI Firmware Device - FD file) is a collection of UEFI binaries encapsulated into a single image. The format of this image is defined by the Platform Initialization Specification Volume 3. A Vector Table is located at the base of this file. A 'BL' branch instruction at the base of the firwmare (location of the Reset Entry into the Vector Table) will jump to the first 'SEC' module of the UEFI Firmware Image.
       >
       > --- https://github.com/lzeng14/tianocore/wiki/ArmPkg-Debugging

       - To verify the statements above:

         - Disassember the reset vector (i.e., the 1st word) of generated `.FD` (we got offset=`0x360`):

           ```
           $ xxd -l 4 -e TEST.fd       <== dump 4 bytes in little endian
           00000000: 140000d8          <== BL   {PC}+(0xd8<<2); offset=0x360
           ```
         - Check the Entry point in `.dll` (we got offset=`0x240`):

           ```
           $ aarch64-none-elf-objdump -t ArmPlatformPrePiUniCore.dll|grep _ModuleEntryPoint
           0000000000000240 g     F .text  0000000000000000 _ModuleEntryPoint
           $ readelf -h ArmPlatformPrePiUniCore.dll|grep Entry
           Entry point address:               0x240
           ```
         - Compare contents of two files at different offset (we got identicial content):

           ```
           $ xxd -s 0x360 -l 64 TEST.fd                      <== skip 0x360 bytes, dump 64 bytes
           00000360: 901e 0094 050a 0094 ea03 00aa a1cd 0a58  ...............X
           00000370: 0200 e0d2 2200 c0f2 0240 a0f2 0200 80f2  ...."....@......
           00000380: c303 a0d2 e3ff 9ff2 6304 00d1 6300 028b  ........c...c...
           00000390: 0400 a1d2 0400 80f2 2000 03eb 8400 0054  ........ ......T
           $ xxd -s 0x240 -l 64 ArmPlatformPrePiUniCore.dll  <== skip 0x240 bytes
           00000240: 901e 0094 050a 0094 ea03 00aa a1cd 0a58  ...............X
           00000250: 0200 e0d2 2200 c0f2 0240 a0f2 0200 80f2  ...."....@......
           00000260: c303 a0d2 e3ff 9ff2 6304 00d1 6300 028b  ........c...c...
           00000270: 0400 a1d2 0400 80f2 2000 03eb 8400 0054  ........ ......T
           ```
2. Prepare an *empty* pkg, and make it build ok. The main purpuse is to do some exercise with EDK2 build system, and use the empty pkg as the start point for the new platform.

   - Make a copy of `RaspberryPi.dec`, change all `gRaspberry` to `gMyPlatform`.
   - Make a copy of `RPi4.dsc` and `RPi4.fdf`, and comment out all stuff in `DSC` and `FDF` file.
   - Replace all GUIDs in `DSC`/`FDF`/`DEC` files, generating new ones using [online guid generator](https://guidgenerator.com/).
   - Note that PCD are declared in `DEC` files, and DEC files are refered by modules (`INF` files). As the empty package contains no module, no PCD definition will be available in `FDF`. So for a success build of the empty package, we need to comment out all PCD reference in `FDF`.
   - The `NOOPT` build command for `MyPlatform` is as below:

     ```
     #!/bin/bash

     export WORKSPACE=/home/bruin/work/tianocore
     export PACKAGES_PATH=$WORKSPACE/edk2:$WORKSPACE/edk2-platforms:$WORKSPACE/edk2-non-osi
     pushd $WORKSPACE
     source edk2/edksetup.sh

     echo "Building BaseTools..."
     make -C edk2/BaseTools all

     echo "Building UEFI firmware for MyPlatform..."
     GCC5_AARCH64_PREFIX=aarch64-none-linux-gnu- build \
           -n 4 \
           -a AARCH64 \
           -p Platform/MyCorp/MyPlatform/MyPlatform.dsc \
           -t GCC5 \
           -b NOOPT \
           -v -d 9 -j MyPlatform-build.log \
           -y MyPlatform-build-report.txt \
           -Y EXECUTION_ORDER \
           -Y PCD \
           -Y LIBRARY \
           -Y DEPEX \
           -Y HASH \
           -Y BUILD_FLAGS \
           -Y FLASH \
           -Y FIXED_ADDRESS \
           all
     popd
     ```
3. Add the 1st component `ArmPlatformPrePiUniCore`. This component is to prepare the HOBs for DXE phae. The main purpose is to get serial port working and memory config correct. Another purpose of this step is to familiar with steps for adding a component/module/lib. Below is a brief summary of the steps:

   - Uncomment the module's `INF` into both `DSC` (`[Components]` section), and `FDF` (`[FV.FVMAIN_COMPACT]`).
   - Rebuild the pkg, and resolve all `Instance of library class [xxxLib] is not found` errors reported, by updating `[LibraryClasses]` sections of `DSC`.

     - This step is a repeating process for dozens of times.
     - Some lib-class has multiple lib-instances, making sure choose the appropriate lib-instance (ref the build-report of RPi4).
     - if encounter `ModuleEntryPoint.iiii:31: Error: immediate out of range`: enable `gArmTokenSpaceGuid.PcdFdBaseAddress` and `gArmTokenSpaceGuid.PcdFdSize` in `FDF`.
     - if encounter `undefined reference to _gPcd_BinaryPatch_PcdSerialClockRate`: set `PcdSerialClockRate` in `[PcdsPatchableInModule]` section in `DSC`. FIXME: why? [ref](https://edk2-docs.gitbook.io/edk-ii-dsc-specification/3_edk_ii_dsc_file_format/39_pcd_sections).
   - Check the PCDs listed in build log: inspect any abnormal PCD values, and supply correct values.
   - Customize platform-specific drivers or libraries.

     - `SerialPortLib`: locate the lib-class header file (`MdePkg/Include/Library/SerialPortLib.h`) by `find edk2 -type f -name "*.dec" -exec grep -Hn SerialPortLib`. The following functions are required:

       - `SerialPortInitialize()`
       - `SerialPortWrite()`
       - `SerialPortRead()`
       - `SerialPortPoll()`
       - `SerialPortSetControl()`: RETURN_UNSUPPORTED
       - `SerialPortGetControl()`: RETURN_UNSUPPORTED
       - `SerialPortSetAttributes()`: RETURN_UNSUPPORTED
     - `ArmPlatformLib`: interface header at `Include/Library/ArmPlatformLib.h`. The following functions are required:

       - `ArmPlatformGetCorePosition()`: return cpu idx in the cluster given the MPIDR value. this function is used in `_ModuleEntryPoint` for setting stack for secondary cores. Assuming one cluster for now.
       - `ArmPlatformIsPrimaryCore()`
       - `ArmPlatformGetPrimaryCoreMpId()`
       - `ArmPlatformGetBootMode()`
       - `ArmPlatformPeiBootAction()`
       - `ArmPlatformInitialize()`
       - `ArmPlatformGetVirtualMemoryMap()`
       - `ArmPlatformGetPlatformPpiList()`
     - etc...
4. Uncomment more modules in DSC/FDF, module by module...For driver/libs which are RPi platform specific, we can:

   - either search the `edk2`/`edk2-platform` for similiar driver or lib instances, or
   - copy the RPi4 implementation and comment out most of the content, make the pkg build success first, and then bug fixing.
5. Debugging: my current main debugging method is through adding "printf()", i.e., the edk2 macro `DEBUG((DEBUG_INFO,))`. One needs to set `gEfiMdePkgTokenSpaceGuid.PcdDebugPrintErrorLevel` to an appropriate value to see more debug info.

Comment: Hello, I am very interested in your post because I am doing the same project like that. Can you give me your contact (email, LinkedIn, Facebook, etc.) ? I would like to discuss with you more. Thanks a lot!

Comment: After fixing this error:
if encounter undefined reference to _gPcd_BinaryPatch_PcdSerialClockRate: set PcdSerialClockRate in [PcdsPatchableInModule] section in DSC

I have a new error: undefined reference to `memcpy'